# cant clone project from heroku - (in other computer)

Tags: git, heroku, git-clone, heroku-cli

i logged in to heroku and trying clone my project from there but i getting some problem with credentials. i'm not understand what i missed..

copy paste from the cmd:

```
D:\---...>heroku login
heroku: Enter your login credentials
Email [------@gmail.com]:
Password: **************************
Logged in as -----@gmail.com

D:\---...>heroku git:clone -a project-name
Cloning into 'project-name'...
remote: !       WARNING:
remote: !       Do not authenticate with username and password using git.
remote: !       Run `heroku login` to update your credentials, then retry the git command.
remote: !       See documentation for details: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#http-git-authentication
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://git.heroku.com/project-name.git/'
```

i didn't logged with git , i checked the docs [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#http-git-authentication) (no solution..), 
i tried also clone the project to c:\ same problem, i saw the netrc file updated with the token everything looks good - what is the problem ?!

btw when i connecting from the first computer (that created the app and push updates etc..) there isn't any problem to clone/push etc..

same steps - different results...

Comment: This probably isn't your problem, but tince [cloning from Heroku is only offered as a convenience](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app), consider using a proper repository host like GitHub, GitLab, or Bitbucket alongside Heroku.

Comment: Is your Heroku CLI fully updated?

Comment: yes. the newest cli.